# Running Glype Proxy - Frequent Server Error - Number of Processes reaching allowed number

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I am running a Glype proxy. Frequently, the site experiences "Internal server error".

At this time when I log in to my cPanel, I see in red "Number of processes: 10/10".

When I approach the support, they tell me that the site exceeded allowed resource usage. One of the support guys suggested that I may use PHP / MySQL Connection closed or die method.

Kindly guide me to avoid this error. I can edit the php files.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies use up a lot of resources, if you use shared hosting upgrade to a vps or dedicated. It's not a problem you can fix, but since it's glype, you can disable gzip compression to help.